# how to download a file to local machine instead of grid node in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, selenium-grid2

in my organization we are using protractor with selenium grid. we have download and edit downloaded excel file functionality Locally i am able to verify whether file downloaded by using "fs.existsSync(filename)" and editing that using protractor.

my grid is like hub(windows7 which is local machine) and 1 node(windows 10 virtual machine) when i clicked on download its downloading to VM machine.

i am unable to access that downloaded file and unable to edit.

is it possible to download to hub machine instead of node(VM)

i am using java script for developing scripts

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thanks for replay,i want to download file to my hub machine instead of node machine or is there any way that i can interact with node file system

Comment: Can you tell the configuration of project like
1. which grid u r using e.g. selenium grid ?
2. hub is on remote machine and node are on local machine ?

Currently what I can suggest is you can first send file to local using command like scp remotemachineip@username:/path to file path to file in source machine